# How can I do to put the edit input into my react project?

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

Hello I have that edit input :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.0.7/css/boxicons.min.css" />
<script defer src="https://unpkg.com/alpinejs@3.9.1/dist/cdn.min.js"></script>

<main class="flex min-h-screen w-full items-center justify-center bg-gray-100">
    <div x-data="{ open : false }" class="p-2 bg-white border shadow rounded w-96">
        <div x-show="!open" class="flex justify-between items-center">
            <div class="ml-2">Hafiz Haziq</div>
            <button type="button" class="btn bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-600 text-white px-4 py-2 font-medium rounded "
                @click="open = !open">Edit</button>
        </div>

        <!-- container after clicked "EDIT" -->
        <div x-show="open" class="flex justify-between items-center">
            <input type="text" class="w-full bg-gray-100 rounded p-2 mr-4" value="Hafiz Haziq">

            <div class="flex justify-center items-center space-x-2">
                <button type="button" class="rounded bg-emerald-500 hover:bg-emerald-600 w-10 h-10 text-white text-3xl">
                    <i class='bx bx-check'></i>
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="rounded bg-red-500 hover:bg-red-600 text-white w-10 h-10 text-3xl"
                    @click="open = false">
                    <i class='bx bx-x'></i>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</main>
```

that I found here : [The edit input](https://tailwindcomponents.com/component/edit-input)

And I would like to put it into my react project :

I tried that :

```
import "./styles.css";

const App = ()=> {
  return (
    <main class="flex min-h-screen w-full items-center justify-center bg-gray-100">
    <div x-data="{ open : false }" class="p-2 bg-white border shadow rounded w-96">
        <div x-show="!open" class="flex justify-between items-center">
            <div class="ml-2">Hafiz Haziq</div>
            <button type="button" class="btn bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-600 text-white px-4 py-2 font-medium rounded "
                @click="open = !open">Edit</button>
        </div>

        {/*<!-- container after clicked "EDIT" --> */}
        <div x-show="open" class="flex justify-between items-center">
            <input type="text" class="w-full bg-gray-100 rounded p-2 mr-4" value="Hafiz Haziq" />

            <div class="flex justify-center items-center space-x-2">
                <button type="button" class="rounded bg-emerald-500 hover:bg-emerald-600 w-10 h-10 text-white text-3xl">
                    <i class='bx bx-check'></i>
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="rounded bg-red-500 hover:bg-red-600 text-white w-10 h-10 text-3xl"
                    @click="open = false">
                    <i class='bx bx-x'></i>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</main>
  );
}

export default App;
```

The code of the full project is there : [My project](https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-darkness-5dffn3?file=/src/App.js:0-1320)

But it does not work ...

Could you help me please ?

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

It is not working, because this is not a React code. You would need to change few things in there.

You need use useState to keep track of open state

```
const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
```

To handle click events on button you should use onClick instead of @click

```
<button onClick={() => setOpen(true)}>
  Edit
</button>
```

Change places where you are defining classes for HTML elements. In react you should use className keyword for that.

```
<div className="ml-2">Hafiz Haziq</div>
```

You can also remove x-data and x-show attributes

```
<div x-show="!open" class="flex justify-between items-center">
```